# How to rename a folder in ADF(Azure data factory) pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am relatively new to azure. I just want to know is there any way to rename a folder using azure pipeline. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what folder? Windows file system folder? Azure Storage folder? Or ADF portal UI folder?

Comment: folder in a windows file system

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?If my answer helps you,you could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my understanding, i think your question is equivalent to asking:

> how to execute windows commands or scripts to manipulate vm file
>   system in ADF.

There is no direct way based on my knowledge because ADF is used for data transfer mostly. As a workaround,you could consider the agency model.

1.Create an API and expose it in the on-premise environment. Its responsibility is to accept the parameters and rename the local folder according to the specified parameters.

2.Use [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) to call the expose API,pass the target folder name as parameters to that API.

Anyway, ADF has little value in this process, unless you have to do something else in ADF.